# Get the first word of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I would like to get the first word of a string and save it to a variable.  I know that `string.split()` method works if you know what you want to split at.  Whats stumping me is that the strings I have are not always the same.  Here are some example strings and what I want to save is bolded.

1. "**LEAD**, UNFILTERED TOTAL"
2. "**PH(-LOG H+ CONCN)**"
3. "**STREAM CONDITION**"
4. "**NITRATES** TOTAL, UNFIL.REAC"
5. "**TETRACHLOROBENZENE 1,2,3,4**" <-- that is one chemical name

So is there something I can use that will satisfy the 5 examples I have here? Or will I have to search manually for each one and deal with it that way?

What I was thinking is to check for the format of each string I get.  So if the string has no commas (no. 2 & 3), take the entire string; if it has commas, then split at the first non-letter character (like a space or comma).  The last one, however, will not word for no. 5 as I want the entire string as well.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you mean to only bold 'stream' in 'stream condition'?? And you should change your title to 'word' instead of 'letter'.

Comment: I'd say you've solved it yourself!  Now build a regular expression filter that matches your test case and you'll be done.

Comment: @danronmoon no, I would like both words.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Ok, thanks.  I know the pattern I would use for example 2, 3, and 5.  But how would I do no. 1 and 4? I was thinking to check for any number of letters followed by a non-letter character and only keep the first letters but that wouldn't satisfy the second example.

Comment: You may have to do perform more than one comparison.  In other words, you may have to use more than one regular expression test.

Comment: Explain why the first word is not just "stream"

Comment: @STLDeveloper thanks.  I'll give that a try and see how it goes.

Comment: @Bohemian The data I have been given is from the gov't and is about water quality.  So these strings are the parameters they tested the waters with.  So in english,  the first example is that an unfiltered sample of water was taken and x amount of lead was found.  So stream condition is the the parameter they were testing the water for. Hopefully that clears it up.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is essentially impossible, simply because the names you are listing have no common pattern. The last example alone would break things as it includes a space and a comma in the word while other examples need to break on space and commas!

The only way I can think of to reliable do this would be to have a dictionary of the chemical names/words/etc that you are using and then you can check against that dictionary until you find a match.

Store the dictionary in a `HashSet` or `HashMap` and you can quickly check for a match, just scan your string looking for the first non-alphanumeric. Check if what you have found so far is in the Set, if it is not repeat the process to continue scanning until you either do find a match or run out of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
       String  lines[]= {"LEAD, UNFILTERED TOTAL","PH(-LOG H+ CONCN)","STREAM CONDITION","NITRATES TOTAL, UNFIL.REAC","TETRACHLOROBENZENE 1,2,3,4"};
       String COMMA=",";
       String REGEX="(^(\\w|\\+|\\-|\\(|\\))+(\\W?,?\\d)*)";
       Pattern res=Pattern.compile(REGEX);
       Pattern resComma=Pattern.compile(COMMA);
       Matcher match;
       for(String line:lines){
         if(!resComma.matcher(line).find()){
          System.out.println(" RESULT "+ line);  
         }
         else if ((match=res.matcher(line)).find())
          System.out.println(" RESULT "+ match.group());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to use a regular expression you could use a break iterator - `java.text.BreakIterator`.

To get the words in a string use:

```
BreakIterator iter = BreakIterator.getWordInstance();

iter.setText(text);

for (int loc = iter.first(), lastLoc = 0; loc != BreakIterator.DONE; loc = lastLoc, loc = iter.next)
 {
    if (loc == 0)
       continue;

    String word = text.substring(lastLoc, loc);
 }
```

Break iterators are used to find 'boundaries' in text - which might be words or sentences or something else. The example above uses the predefined word break iterator which returns the index of the beginning of a word or punctuation characters and moves through the text on successive calls. The loop is just extracting the words by using the current and previous locations returned by the iterator, punctuation will be extracted as separate words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Would you mind explaining what that does?